# what is the difference about SCHEMA in sql server 2005 and sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, schema

what is the difference about SCHEMA in sql server 2005 and sql server 2008?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that any changes were made to the SCHEMA implementation between 2005 and 2008, although I believe if we are talking about 2005 RTM, there were some slight changes to system functions that came about in 2005 SP2, for example OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME() was added, and OBJECT_ID() was modified to add a second parameter, database_id.  So you would notice these differences if comparing functionality in 2005 RTM or SP1 to functionality in 2008.

Perhaps if you have a more specific question about schema (or perhaps you mean something completely different than how I interpreted) - can you give more details about what information you are after?

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Please give me more information about security issues.

Comment: Again, could you be more specific?  What "security issues" do you think changed in 2008 w.r.t. schema?  You can use SQL Server Audit against a schema to audit all actions performed under that schema, but I can't think of anything else specifically that might be of interest.

Comment: please see this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221929/what-is-the-importance-of-schema-in-sql-server

Comment: I still don't understand how to answer your question further... are there questions you had in that thread that weren't answered, or that I haven't already answered?